# How to verify that an object file was generated by g++ and not by gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

On my linux box (ubuntu), is there any way to verify that an object file was created from my c sources using g++ and not via gcc? 
With `readelf`, I'm able to read the gcc version that was used to create the object file. unfortunately it does not tell if g++ or gcc was used. maybe there is a debug option to put that info in the comment somehow?

Comment: That may be meaningless. You can call `gcc -x c++` and `g++ -x c`, so what exactly do you want to find out?

Comment: I'm working on native binary support in gradle. In one testcase I replace the gcc default for compiling c sources with g++. Now I need to verify that in that test indeed the reconfigured g++ executable was used. I guess the resulting .o files are identical so I might need to come up with a different test scenario

Comment: Will something like `nm <your object> | grep CXXABI` work? Or, may be egrep for "_Z.+" (to detect if any symbol names are mangled).

Comment: Replace g++ with a shell script which calls `gcc -x c++` and also creates some sentinel file named after the source file (but with an added extension). Then make sure that sentinel file was created.

Comment: @GoodPerson: `readelf` is a Linux utility.  On what basis do you claim to know the `linux` tag is not appropriate here?

Comment: @hardmath since (a) readelf works on more than just Linux and (b) this question is answerable on more than just Linux

Comment: @GoodPerson: You have not offered any Answer, and editing the Question to change its meaning by removing explicit reference to the platform (Ubuntu) where the OP needs a solution is unjustified.

Comment: @GoodPerson I rolled back your changes as in both cases it's the same (c) code. I just wanted to know if there is a way to figure out if g++ or gcc was used for compiling. I can see that in the comment section of that object file the gcc version information differs when using g++/gcc. But this is not reliable enough for me

Comment: @ReneGroeschke: by definition this is impossible.  you also neglect clang entirely.  in either case this is *not* linux specific

Comment: If you need to know whether the source is treated as C source or C++ source, use `nm` and look for mangled names. This is not a 100% reliable indication.

Comment: do you mean a elf binary or just the result of gcc -c ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set preprocessor macros in your makefile or GCC commandline (whether gcc or g++) which set static constant strings in each object file, to record how things were built and what sourcefile version (if you care about maintenance & support in field).  Copy the way source code control system info gets stored in some FOSS programs.

Then you can use the strings(1) to check the info saved.

GCC, provides both  driver programs gcc & g++, to compile and/or link C & C++, setting appropriate defaults, but options mean C++ can be compiled using gcc, as well as C (often) being valid input to a C++ compiler.  Options can be recorded by compiler switches `-frecord-gcc-switches` on some targets, or the debugging option `-grecord-gcc-switches` but compilers are compared on how lean and fast their output is, so you have to ask explicitly for such "bloat" and it may not even care which command was used to invoke the compiler.

For a built exectutable, ldd can be useful, nm for object as suggested in comments

```
ldd ./sob
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc37fe000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7e99378000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7e99075000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7e98e5e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e98aaf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e99680000)

    nm ./sob.o
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
..
                 U _ZSt4cerr
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
0000000000000008 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
nm ./mallocstats.o
                 U fprintf
                 U mallinfo
0000000000000000 T mallocstats
                 U stderr
```

THe libstdc++.so.6 suggests ./sob is C++ and that's correct.  Mangled names and things like cerr/cout and basic_ostream, really indicate C++.  The C-ness of mallocstats.o is not in doubt either.

Comment: This doesnt actually answer the question. The question is not "how can I tell if it is compiled as C or C++", but "Can i tell if gcc or g++ was invoked". Both gcc and g++ can compile C and C++ code.

Comment: That's what the first paragraph addresses, it's a technique I've seen used and used myself, but requires source changes and planning ahead. Some ppl who google "object gcc or g++" type queries, may know that gcc or g++ are not inovoked with "clever" options, so ldd & nm  would effectively answer the question.  Sometimes if you want information you need to plan ahead, though it's possible gcc, leaves traces depending on it's invocation, I've never come across such info

Comment: thanks for this answer. unfortunately I'm not using make but plain gcc / g++.

Comment: You can define things on the command line.. with -D switch.  If you haven't got an automated build system, then I think you have a small project.  Therefore, the simplest thing is just to recompile your object code with gcc or g++ and then you can be certain how it was built :)

Answer (score 0):

Given `addnum.c`:

```
int adnum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Use `nm addnum.o` to identify if the object file of `addnum.c` is compiled by `gcc` `(by gcc -c addnum.c)` or `g++` `(by g++ -c addnum.c)`.

If compiled by `gcc`:

```
nm addnum.o
0000000000000000 T addnum
```

If compiled by `g++`:

```
nm addnum.o
0000000000000000 T _Z6addnumii
```

That is, the **name mangling** of the `addnum` function name is the tell.

Comment: this does not work is function are extern "C"

Comment: That is a different topic. The caller knows it is C so no need for it. Take note, it is `addnum.c`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution (workaround) that came to mind. You need to add the following into source code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { int __compiled_using_cplusplus; }
#endif
```

You can find `__compiled_using_cplusplus` symbol in object file only if the source was compiled using g++:

```
alexander@ubuntu:tmp4$ nm test-g++.o 
0000000000000000 B __compiled_using_cplusplus

alexander@ubuntu:tmp4$ nm test-gcc.o

alexander@ubuntu:tmp4$ nm test-g++.o | grep -q '__compiled_using_cplusplus' && echo "c++ compiler"
c++ compiler

alexander@ubuntu:tmp4$ nm test-gcc.o | grep -q '__compiled_using_cplusplus' && echo "c++ compiler"
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, because you can use gcc options to compile the same as 'g++'.  -D__cplusplus would be required for gcc to compile C++ code

Comment: @Rob11311, have you seen such invocation of gcc anywhere in real world?

Comment: I think actually I have, but back in the 90's :)  Really the problem with this, is the question.  A developer who's not documented or automated his build and is therefore unsure how he compiled something.